# Split labels over 2 lines in ggplot with factors

Tags: r, string, ggplot2, label

I have a plot whose labels are factors of the form "1990-2012". They are too long and/or there are too many of them and they overlap.

[image]

I would like to print each label over two lines and break it after the hyphen, something like this:

[image]

For situations where breaking the labels into two parts would still not suffice, I would also like to know how to print only every other label.

A constraint I have is that the labelling should be done "in-place" without pre-processing of the data.frame and/or labels, though a custom function applied within the call to ggplot would be fine.

Here is the sacrosanct dataframe (cannot be altered):

```
    df <- structure(list(Period = structure(1:13, .Label = c("0-1000", 
    "1000-1500", "1500-1700", "1700-1820", "1820-1913", "1913-1950", 
    "1950-1970", "1970-1990", "1990-2012", "2012-2030", "2030-2050", 
    "2050-2070", "2070-2100"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.000168759866884916, 
    0.000989913144738397, 0.00159894629454382, 0.0045594248070473, 
    0.00585564273031225, 0.00932876890888812, 0.0191066122563939, 
    0.0183146076484786, 0.0130117469870081, 0.00923670910453378, 
    0.00560791817163286, 0.00272731553972227, 0.00149387241891397
    ), variable = c("World", "World", "World", "World", "World", 
    "World", "World", "World", "World", "World", "World", "World", 
    "World")), .Names = c("Period", "value", "variable"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the ggplot:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Period, y = value, group = variable)) + geom_line() + theme_bw()
```

The following would work, if I had a space after the hyphen:

```
  library(stringr)
  p + scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 4))
```

[The two lines above were used to produce the second plot, after I had manually altered the dataframe to add a blank space after the date-separating hyphen, in other words, after I cheated]

The following approach to print fewer labels usually works, but fails here:

```
   library(scales)
   p + scale_x_discrete(breaks = pretty_breaks(n = 6))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
p + scale_x_discrete(
  labels=function(x){
    x2 <- sub("(\\d+)\\-(\\d+)",
               "\\1\\-\n\\2",
               x)
    x2
  })
```

[image]

Actually the intermediate `x2` isn't even necessary, this

```
p + scale_x_discrete(
  labels=function(x){
    sub("(\\d+)\\-(\\d+)","\\1\\-\n\\2",x)
  })
```

is a little more compact.

**Edit:** 
An even more concise solution, thanks to @jlhoward:

```
p + scale_x_discrete(
  labels=function(x) sub("-","-\n",x,fixed=TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks @nrussell, in the meantime I realized that I could use ``str_replace`` from the ``stringr`` package. I had missed that, I had wasted time on ``str_sub`` not realizing there was a ``str_replace`` for the job. The ``stringr`` solution is: ``p + scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(str_replace(x,"-","- "), width = 4))``

Comment: A solution along the lines you suggest is what I expected, but I just don't know how these backslashes and ``d+`` work and convinced myself I could never work it out. And looking at the term inside ``sub()``, it's clear I couldn't come up with that alone! Thanks, :-)

Comment: You're welcome; `\\d+` is shorthand for "1 or more consecutive digits" in regular expression syntax. The backslashes preceding the hyphen may or may not have been necessary - some regex symbols have special meaning and need to be escaped (double escaped in R and some other languages) in order to be interpreted literally; I always forget exactly which ones so I do it with most symbols just to be safe. `\\1` references the first capture group (the `(\\d+)`), and `\\2` references the second `(\\d+)`. See [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If you copy the explanation in your answer and make space by removing the first code with the intermediate ``x2``, I think it would be very useful for future users (and my future self). Sometimes dates come in the form ``"1990/2012"`` so it's useful to know about escaping slashes and backslashes; or more complicated forms where my ``str_replace`` approach may not work, while yours would. +1!

Comment: This also works, and avoids both the need to escape the delimiters, and the use of `str_wrap(...)`: `p+scale_x_discrete(
    labels=function(x)sub("-","-\n",x,fixed=TRUE))`